# How to manually assign weights to some features in SVM?

Tags: svm, libsvm, feature-selection, liblinear

I ran a multi class SVM using LibLinear but the Model is giving high weights to certain typical features for every class.

For Ex: For Class 1, a particular variable which is 0 for Class 1 and non-zero otherwise has a very dominating weight in my hyperplane equation.

I want to ignore these specific features while computing hyperplanes for the specific classes. One way is to assign Zero Weights to those features. How do I change the code for this?

For Ex:

```
For Class 1, I assign W=0 for Feature_1
For Class 2, I assign W=0 for Feature_2
For Class 3, I assign W=0 for Feature_3
```

and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to do it by hand. Multi-class SVM is just a bunch of SVMs trained independently. You can do it on your own, each time removing different feature.

Comment: Yeah. But I am not being able to break through the code. I needed help with the code itself...